# Changes on LiveData does not update UI

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

i have :

```
var mFinalData : LiveData<FinalData>= Transformations.map(mRepository.getCart()) { it -> transformCurrentCart(it) }
```

from witch i fill my UI. But when i try to modify on var from inside my mFinalData using a click button the new value is set inside my LiveData but does not update my UI

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not giving the code of your Observer, I'm assuming you're not using one.

A LiveData won't update your UI by itself, you need to Observe those change using an Observer.

```
mFinalData.observe(this, Observer {
    //UI behavior
})
```

[Observe LiveData Object](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects)

Comment: ok. how can i rebind my livedata to my xml with couple of line of code without setting each value to each view ?